# Cohen's d for pairwise t.tests - conflicting results from manual calculation and effsize package

Tags: r, effect-size, cohens-d

I am running a paired-samples t.test and trying to calculate Cohen's d. By now I have two different results (effsize v effectsize packages) and would greatly appreciate any help with figuring out how they are related.

First, I tried it by hand, using the t.test object (saved as tt):

```
tt$estimate/(sqrt(tt$parameter+1)*tt$stderr)
```

That gives me 0.6575. This is exactly the result I get from

```
df %$% effectsize::cohens_d(ctPosFreq, ctNegFreq, paired = T)
```

However, the effsize package gives me a completely different result.

```
df %$% effsize::cohen.d(ctPosFreq, ctNegFreq, paired = T)
```

which results in 0.9283. That's now a different ballpark.

The effectsize package states in the documentation that it is using the method from Gibbons, Hedeker and Davis (1993) to estimate the effect size in that case, but I cannot quite figure out where in their paper they propose a method for the calculation of the d for a single sample, and how that differs from the more straight-forward attempt.

Many thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: There are several different effect sizes, called the same "Cohen's d" for paired test.　
I hope the following articles will be helpful.　http://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/paired-sample-t-test/cohens-d-paired-samples/

Comment: Thanks a lot - that might well explain the difference, and confirms, in any case, that the first approach makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `effsize::cohen.d(..., paired = TRUE, within = TRUE)` which gives a somewhat different estimate of Cohen's *d*.

However, if you set `within = FALSE`, both give the same results, also known as Cohen's *d<sub>z</sub>*:

```r
x <- sleep$extra[sleep$group == 1]
y <- sleep$extra[sleep$group == 2]

effectsize::cohens_d(x, y, paired = TRUE)
#> Cohen's d |         95% CI
#> --------------------------
#> -1.28     | [-2.23, -0.44]

effsize::cohen.d(x, y, paired = TRUE, within = FALSE)
#> 
#> Cohen's d
#> 
#> d estimate: -1.284558 (large)
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>      lower      upper 
#> -2.1820827 -0.3870324
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>